# Sportfire to Power BI Graph

Tags: powerbi, spotfire, spotfire-analyst

I am trying to replicate a report created in Spotfire into Power BI. I am stuck with one of the visuals. Any work around or idea will be appreciated.

[image]

I tried creating this chart in Power BI into a **stacked bar chart** viz but that does not help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use two stacked bar charts. Add some text boxes if you need them. Use the 'Lock Objects' on the format page to stop things from moving around. Lock and hide the filter pane if you need to. Put a nice background behind it to create am impression.

Comment: This is what I have done but was wondering if there is a better way to show this.

Comment: I think you have dome this the best way you can with Power BI